# How do I change the style of disabled tabs in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I am trying to adjust the style of some disabled tab titles, and I'm having no luck figuring out the right way to do it. I'd like to change the background color, text color (and probably font-weight), and having it even showing as a link. 
I have this tab:

`<b-tab title="Internal To Your Council" disabled></b-tab>`

It has the same background as the other tabs, set so:

```
.nav-tabs {
  background-color: #323232;
}
```

I've got a few other stylings, as well, but none of the ways I've tried to stick "disabled" onto them have produced anything useful. 
Those other stylings:

```
/* tab color */
.nav-tabs>li>a {
  border-color: #777777;
  color:#fff;
}

/* active tab color */
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
  color: #323232;
}

/* hover tab color */
.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
  border-color: #000000;
}
```

I've toyed with just adding a class on the  declaration, but that doesn't update the whole tab background. Is there not a way to do that? If not, I'll just content myself with a different font color, but I'd love to be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [bootstrap documentation for tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#tabs), for disabled tabs, it adds a class `disabled` on the `.nav-link`. So have you looked into

```
.nav-tabs {
    .nav-link {
        &.disabled {
            // styles for disabled tabs
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to stick `disabled` class into the class attribute and want to use `disabled` attribute on the nav-link instead, you still can do

```
.nav-tabs {
    .nav-link {
        &:disabled {
            // styles for disabled tabs
        }
    }
}
```